# Make buttons in GridLayout fill empty space

Tags: java, android, mobile

Need help at stretching my buttons in **GridLayout** so they would take all of the free space under the **TextView**

[image]

Here is my hierarchy

[image]

P.S. source code:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display" />
```

Answer (score 1):

check if you are assigning the height and width in px, and change them to % (percentage).. is there any way you can show the source ?

P.S. this is how i fixed it.. i've changed it to Linear

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re``s-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display" />

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: is there any way you can show the whole code for the layout,  you are only showing a small part.. and i can't seem to mimic the problem you are having..

Comment: i just want my buttons to fill out the whole space under the TextView and thats it. what part of my question you can't understand?